# Request Timeout NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlsession

hello I used this below code to send a request to Server. How can I add the timeout in this function

```
static func postToServer(url:String,var params:Dictionary<String,NSObject>, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, String?) -> Void ) -> NSURLSessionTask {


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)


        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    if(params["data"] != "get"){
        do {

            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)

            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("dataString is  \(dataString)")

            request.HTTPBody = data


        } catch {
            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print("error is \(error)")
            //return
        }

    }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {data, response, error -> Void in
            // handle error

            guard error == nil else { return }
            request.timeoutInterval = 10


           print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
             completionHandler(nil,"Body: \(strData!)")
          //print("Body: \(strData!)")

            let json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let dataError {
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                print(dataError)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
              print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                completionHandler(nil,"Body: \(jsonStr!)")

                // return or throw?
                return
            }


            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it

                completionHandler(parseJSON,nil)
                //let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                //print("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Errors could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                completionHandler(nil,"Body: \(jsonStr!)")
            }

        }

        task.resume()
        return task
    }
```

I did some search too and I came to know about to use this function

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)
```

instead of this

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
```

But problem is If I used the above function then I can't set these variables

```
request.HTTPBody = data
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Please anyone suggest me correct solution of how to add timeout in my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify your request because for some reason you went with immutable option. Since NSMutableURLRequest is a subclass of NSURLRequest you can use the very same initializer `init(URL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:)` to create an *mutable* instance and set default timeout. And then configure (mutate) this request as you need.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)
```

Comment: okay Thanks. its working. One last question I would like to ask is How can i return nil to my calling function. I am doing this   if(response == nil){
               

            completionHandler(nil,"nil") but its not working

Answer (score 4):

`NSMutableRequest` has a property `timeoutInterval` which you can set.
 [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/timeoutInterval) is Apple's documentation which shows you how to set a timeout.

*They have stated*

> *If during a connection attempt the request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request is considered to have timed out. The default timeout interval is **60** **seconds**.*

Please note that the timeout does ***not*** guarantee that the network call will get terminated if the network call does ***not*** complete within the timeout.

ie: Suppose you set the timeout to 60 seconds.
The connection might still be active and not terminate after 60 seconds. The timeout occurs if there is **no** data transfer during a complete period of 60 seconds.

> E.g. **Consider the following scenario** *This does NOT incur a timeout*

- t=0 to t=59 seconds => No data transfers **(Total of 59 seconds)**
- t=60 to t=62 => Some data arrives at t=60s **(Total of 2 seconds)**
- t=63 to t=100 => No data transfers **(Total of 37 seconds)**
- t=100 to t=260 => Remaining data transfers and completes the network
  request **(Total of 160 seconds)**

> **Now consider the following scenario**. *Timeout occurs at t=120*

- t=0 to t=59 seconds => Some data transfers until t=59 **(Total of 59 seconds)**
- t=60 to t=120 => No data transfers **(Total of 60 seconds)**

Answer (score 2):

Use **NSURLSessionConfiguration** to specify the Timeout,

```
let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0 //Request Timeout interval 30 sec
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30.0 //Response Timeout interval 30 sec

let session  = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableURLRequest has this method too:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:  NSURL(string: url)!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
```